# Using ElementName within a Resource in a Dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have defined following in a ResourceDictionary:

```xml
<DockPanel x:Key="errorDisplay" LastChildFill="False">
        <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="errorTextBlock" />
        </Border>
        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="15">
            <Polygon 
                Points="{Binding ElementName=errorDisplay, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource PointsToStringArrayConverter},Mode=OneWay}"
                Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />                
        </Canvas>
</DockPanel>
```

This resource is added to an adorner layer in code behind on loading of a usercontrol.

However, I get a binding error

> (Cannot find source for binding with reference
>   'ElementName=errorDisplay')

. I am aware of namescopes, but surely the above should work as it all takes place within the single composite control, with the same namescope applying?

EDIT (Using RelativeSource/AncestorType instead of elementname does not seem to work either.) Does work! But actualwidth is Nil

EDIT: using ElementName=errorTextBlock also results in same binding error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't named the DockPanel you have provided a resource key.

Try `<DockPanel x:Key="errorDisplay" x:Name="errorDisplay" LastChildFill="False">`

However as you say, this doesn't work when tested.

A relative source binding seems to work in this cut down version of your code though:

This is in a resource element

```
<DockPanel x:Key="errorDisplay" LastChildFill="False">
    <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBlock x:Name="errorTextBlock" 
         Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource errorDisplay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, however <DockPanel x:Key="errorDisplay" x:Name="dockP" LastChildFill="False"> results in same binding error

Comment: Phil, FindAncestor does get rid of the binding error, but using it on the polygon Points="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource PointsToStringArrayConverter},Mode=OneWay}"/> results in a 0 Actualwidth being passed to the converter. Any ideas why?

Comment: Any way to bind Points="{Binding ElementName=errorTextBlock, ... as RelativeSource does not work (as textblock is not a direct ancestor)

Comment: the x:Name does not work in a ResourceDictionary, probably because it does not really get instantiated. I read somewhere that items in a ResourceDictionary are instantiated only when there accessed/needed by a control in an instanciated class, which meens only names inside the markupitem can be accessed. So it might work if the ResourceDictionary had a class registered to it.

Comment: In your question, you're binding says ElementName=errorDisplay which is a direct ancestor.

Comment: Phil, yes, sorry for the confusion, I meant to ask if either ElementName=errorDisplay or errorTextBlock can work - seems former can bind (but get nil value for path) but latter is not a direct ancestor of polygon

Answer (score 1):

You're using `ElementName=` while pointing to a `x:Key` which is not the same. However you cannot use the `x:Name` to refer to. It's hard finding out on MSDN why it cannot be used, but it probably can be found putting all the pieces together.
I guess the namescope is not registered for items in a ResourceDictionary, only for items within an item in a resource dictionary. Hitting F1 on ResourceDictionary.FindName got me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.findname.aspx
where it says: "Not supported by this Dictionary implementation." Guess that would not answer it but gives me the understanding that we might not easily can do it ourselfs.

As an answer to your question:
This works for me:

ResourceDictionary:

```
<DockPanel x:Key="errorDisplay" LastChildFill="False">
    <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <TextBlock x:Name="errorTextBlock" />
    </Border>
    <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="15">
      <Polygon Points="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DockPanel}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource PointsToStringArrayConverter},Mode=OneWay}" 
               Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
    </Canvas>
  </DockPanel>
```

MainWindow:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource errorDisplay}"/>
```

Converter:

```
  public class PointsToStringArrayConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert( object value , Type targetType , object parameter , System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
      if ( !( value is double ) ) { return value; }
      var dbl = ( double )value;
      PointCollection p = new PointCollection( );
      p.Add( new Point( dbl , dbl ) );
      p.Add( new Point( dbl/2 , dbl ) );
      p.Add( new Point( dbl , dbl/2 ) );
      p.Add( new Point( dbl /2, dbl/2 ) );
      return p;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value , Type targetType , object parameter , System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }
  }
```

You said you already tried using RelativeSource, but try putting a breakpoint in your Converter and see if it gets triggered.

For more info:
Namescopes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx
Resources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742538.aspx

Comment: Thanks Silvermind, Phil also pointed out RelativeSource does bind - the problem I am having now is that ActualWidth is nil when passed to the converter.

Comment: @sturdytree If the ActualWidth is null than the Control that uses the errorDisplay in it's content is either not a child of the UI or it's child(ren) doesn't/don't get rendered to the UI.

Comment: Thanks, the errorDisplay is added to an adorner in code behind (the loaded event for the usercontrol they are all hosted in). Interestingly creating the binding in the code behind works.

Comment: It's going to be a bit hacky overall, so I would suggest creating a `Custom Control` and create some dependencyproperties like ErrorText and IsValid. Bind the ErrorText to a TextBlock Control inside the ControlTemplate and Set the Border inside the ControlTemplate using a Trigger on the Property `Property="IsValid" Value="True"`. If that is your goal, but it very much looks like it:) You can add a ContentPresenter too. Btw you should better use a Grid inside the Border inside the ControlTemplate than a DockPanel in this case.